# is there a function in python (or how ) to escape a double quotes in dictionary-like string?

Tags: python, dictionary, double, quotes

I have a string like the following :

```
{"url":"<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>"}
```

and i wanted to transform the string into dictionary
but the problem, when i use eval(), it failed.

```
>>> s = r'{"url":"<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>"}'
>>> d = eval(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    {"url":"<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>"}
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

given the above example, is there a way to convert string s into a dictionary, so that i can access the value of url by referring to d['url']

Comment: Hello. Where does this string come from ?

Comment: eval can be dangerous as well; See if import ast;ast.literal_eval(s) will work for you.

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval` for this. How did you get that original string?

Comment: It's possible to escape double quotes, but it's not possible to figure out which ones should be escaped here. Specifically, your string contains a double-quoted string that contains another double-quoted string, and only the quotes corresponding to the innermost string should be escaped. However, there's no general way to tell which quotes those are.

Comment: I asked you my question because I think **your problem is an XY problem**. I urge you to read (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56366/can-we-get-people-to-directly-ask-about-their-problems-instead-of-topics-they-th) on the XY problem. Steve Jessop has given you the real solution to your real X - false Y problem : ``Really you need to escape the quotes in the HTML before they get stuck together with the dictionary-like stuff.``

Comment: @eyquem the string was crawled from a web site. and the string was part of java script function. So i have no control on the original javascript string

Answer (score 3):

You're out of luck, because from what you've said the following string is ambiguous:

```
{ "url": "<a href="," foo=": "/>" }
```

Is that supposed to be the dictionary that maps `"url"` to `"<a href="` and `" foo"` to `"/>"`, or is it supposed to be the dictionary that maps `"url"` to a (self-closing) `<a>` tag with attributes `href=","` and `foo=": "`? You could decide for example by disallowing the values to contain unbalanced `<` character, but that is a lot of trouble and I'm not certain that there aren't ambiguous examples even then.

Really you need to escape the quotes in the HTML *before* they get stuck together with the dictionary-like stuff. That way, there won't be two different dictionaries that are both represented by the same string.

For example:

```
>>> repr({ "url" : '<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>' })
'{\'url\': \'<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>\'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use triple quotes to do an "exact" quote.

```
""" stuff """
```

So if you have something like `She said, "Lo, and behold, a viper hath appeared!" And it was so!"` but you want to quote it, you could put it in triple quotes and it would read in the quotes as part of the sentence without bugging out.

It appears, however, that the above doesn't actually help, and I misunderstood your issue. I would instead suggest that you analysize this input with a regex (`{(.*?):(.*?)}` might work.) if it is an input, or change your earlier code if your code generates the string.

If you do use this regex, group(1) will be the key, and group(2) will be the value, just so you know. (group(0) is the whole string, of course)

Comment: This doesn't help much, because the string contains a doubly-nested string that wasn't properly escaped. If it's a literal, the solution is to fix the literal; if it's not, you can't triple-quote it, and triple-quoting wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood the question. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use simple regex or custom parsing and replace the inner " with \" before the eval like so:

```
s = r'{"url":"<a href=\"http://www.blah.com/blah/blah\"> click here </a>"}'
d = eval(s)
>>>d
{'url': '<a href="http://www.blah.com/blah/blah"> click here </a>'}
```

Comment: Hello. I suggest you to read my second comment to the OP's question and particularly this link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56366/can-we-get-people-to-directly-ask-about-their-problems-instead-of-topics-they-th)